# how to get grid view selected row's DataBase id

Tags: asp.net

I have GridView, which is not auto generating columns. In GridView there are 3 columns: one for Checkbox(to delete selected row from DataTable),
one for edit link button(to edit current row),
and the third one is for showing data from DataTable.

I am binding it from DataTable.
I have a primary key in DataTable.
Now my problem is when I am clicking on edit link button I am not getting primary key(id) from 
datatable for selected row in grid view (i think row is not selected when i am clicking on edit link button). I cant take row index to match it with datatable primary key as data bound in GridView is filtered.

What I have tried is, I created one more column in grid view as hidden which is primary key column from DataTable. But for that too I am not getting data in hidden column of row which is clicked for edit.

Someone please help with a new idea, or solution for what i am trying.. thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plese try as follow.. for update, selected ID can be got in gv_RowCommand event. For delection [multiple select checbox] check in btnDelete_Click, `enter code here`

--------------aspx code--------------------------------

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
        onclick="btnDelete_Click" />
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" onrowcommand="gv_RowCommand" 
        onrowupdating="gv_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="Update" text="Update" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="Name" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

---------------code behind---------------------------

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                BindData();
        }

        private void BindData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID");
            dt.Columns.Add("NAME");

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "1";
            dr[1] = "James";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "2";
            dr[1] = "Paul";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "3";
            dr[1] = "Mary";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "4";
            dr[1] = "Susan";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            gv.DataSource = dt;
            gv.DataBind();
        }

        protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Update")
            {
                string id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            }
        }

        protected void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string idList = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gv.Rows[i].FindControl("chkSel");

                if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
                    idList += gv.DataKeys[i].Value.ToString() + ",";
            }
        }
```